# Apex test - conditional logic if there is a picklist dependency

Tags: apex

Firstly, I am an ISV Partner and the code is deployed as part of a managed package, so it is not a single org that I am targeting.

I have some validation happening in my trigger based on whether there is a picklist dependency defined in the subscriber org.

When the test runs, the dependency is not there (as we don't ship it in Gold Master org).

Is there any way to create this dependency just for the purposes of the test?

(I understand that I can use a global field to simulate it and get my coverage up, but wanted to see if there is a better way to do it).

Answer (score 2):

You can [Specify Unpackaged Metadata or Apex Access for Package Version Creation Tests for Second-Generation Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_unpackaged_md.htm), which would allow you to include metadata that's only used for testing purposes. This is the only method available, and only if you're using a Second Generation Managed Package (2GP). If you're still using First Generation Managed Packaging (1GP), then you're primarily stuck with [Dependency Injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/08/effective-dependency-injection-in-apex) (DI), where you insert the dependency at unit test time, which is what I presume you mean by using a "global field to simulate" the metadata. You can do this with the [Stub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm) to intercept a method and return a desired value. This is the standard method for DI, although most people stuck on 1GP probably just use some kind of static variable that is overridden in the unit test. Usually, these variables tend to be set as `@TestVisible private` so that they cannot be accessed outside the class during normal runtime, but can be used inside unit tests.

Comment: Yeah this is kind of what I was thinking, and yes we're on 1GP. Sad to be right :(